# Include another page with Jekyll without displaying Front Matter

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to clone the output of `index.html` in another page, `thanks.html`. It's working, but no matter what I try I end up with `--- layout: default title: example ---` rendered (from `index.html`'s Front Matter) where the file starts.

I've tried:

```
---
layout: default
thanks: true
---
{% capture main %}{% include_relative /index.html %}{% endcapture %}
{{ main }}
```

And:

```
---
layout: default
thanks: true
---
{% include_relative /index.html %} <!-- Same problem with just 'include' -->
```

But I get the same result.

If I drop the line `layout: default` it works, but as expected I don't have a header or footer anymore. I can also get it to work using includes but this makes for a lot of duplication for a page with a single line that's different.

In case it's relevant, I'm running Jekyll version 4.2.2 via docker, and there are no plugins set in my `_config.yml`.

Comment: Related: [jekyll/jekyll#3050](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3050)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fragile hack:

```
{% capture source %}{% include_relative included.html %}{% endcapture %}
{{ source | split: "---" | last }}
```

Just don’t use `---` anywhere in the included document. :)